# AutoPostBack Question

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have a form that contains an external URL I want to post my data to.

The problem is that I have several dropdowns that have AutoPostBack = true property set.  How do I get my form to submit once all the data has been set THEN submit to the external URL without having the submit action occur everytime I change the value in my dropdown control?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you could add a client-side validator that won't let the form post successfully if everything hasn't be filled out. Not sure if that will work (RequireFieldValidator with ClientScript true) but it may.

Otherwise, you'd disable AutoPostBack and do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Well AutoPostBack means it will send a postback request any time any control with that property set on it changes, so if you have it on multiple controls it is going to exhibit the behaviour you don't want.

So what are you trying to do - if we know that it'll give us a better idea of what to recommend.